# list index out of range error in for-if loop

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, indexing, error-handling

I have a dataframe called 'df' with one column called 'word' that looks like this:

[image]

I have code that checks if i in df.word is a word, if it is then 'True' is added to the list 'boo'. While the code works, for some reason it keeps throwing out the error message: Error: The Following Error occured: list index out of range, after a true result is processed:

```
df=pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\hiner\for_pydict.csv")
boo = list()
for i in range df.word:
    meaning=dictionary.meaning(i)
    if meaning is not None:
        d = 'True'
    else:
        d = 'False'
    boo.append(d)
```

The immediate out put is:

```
Error: The Following Error occured: list index out of range
Error: The Following Error occured: list index out of range
Error: The Following Error occured: list index out of range
```

But 'boo' has the result I want:

```
boo
['True', 'False', 'True', 'False', 'True']
```

The error is referring to this line:
    meaning=dictionary.meaning(i)
but I am not sure what I can do to fix it. I've tried taking away the variable, but no dice. Why is this error throwing?  As a work around, howSecond, how can I prevent the error message from printing/displaying. Do I need to change my code, or do I need to apply exception handling and if so, how would I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: The error means you're trying to access an element in a list that is out of range. For example, if a list has 2 elements, you cannot access the 4th element.

Comment: yes, but where in the code is that happening? exactly what am i calling that is out of range? i edited the code, but i get the same result.

Comment: The code you have now doesn't look like it will run. Are you sure?

Comment: thanks, forgot to indent. it runs, but it throws those errors. again, i get the 'boo' list that i desire